# programmatically set PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a preferncescreen page for showing of data only and not saving it for setting

the code is as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Member Subscription Status">


        <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Subscription Status"
    android:summary="Active">
</PreferenceScreen> 

        <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Next Payment Date"
    android:summary="2012-06-21 18:00:00s">
</PreferenceScreen> 
        <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Plan Type"
    android:summary="Family">
</PreferenceScreen> 
    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Right now i am wondering how should i set the summary of the preferncescreen to show on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. have to add a key first

```
android:key="Subscriptionstatus"
```

then in activity

```
Preference pref = findPreference( "Subscriptionstatus" );
pref.setSummary("test");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `Preference` with [findPreference()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and then set the summary with [setSummary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setSummary%28int%29).